# How to use different date formats for different date inputs in jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to use multiple date inputs on same page, some must have format `yy-mm-dd` and others format `yy-mm`. When I added jquery code for `yy-mm` format the input with `yy-mm-dd` format lost dates, only months and years are visible?

```
$(function() {    
  var currentDate = new Date();  
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }); 
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate",currentDate );       
});

$(function() {
    $('.month-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that `yy-mm` and `yy-mm-dd` has any conflicts.I tried the same check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PQfDc/70/).Both the file formats are on same page

Comment: You were right. Problem was CSS `.ui-datepicker-calendar {display:none;}`. Can this CSS be applied only specific HTML input? I want to show only months and years for monthpicker.